# Ubuntu MATE architecture on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3

if Ubuntu MATE have x86 architecture on PC, have it x86 architecture on Raspberry Pi 3 too? Or I have to use x86 emulator?

Answer (score 2):

The raspberry pi 3 runs on a ARM processor rather than a x86 architecture meaning that there is no possible way to do that other than using a emulator as you suggested.